# Percona MySQL Server working but filling the messages log with errors

Tags: mysql, centos7, percona

I have Percona MySQL server 5.7 running under CentOS 7 and although mysql is running without any noticeable errors, it is filling my /var/log/messages with the following every ten seconds:

```
Nov 15 10:07:27 server systemd: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 15 10:07:27 server systemd: Starting MySQL Percona Server...
Nov 15 10:07:27 server mysqld_safe: 171115 10:07:27 mysqld_safe Adding '/usr/lib64/libjemalloc.so.1' to LD_PRELOAD for mysqld
Nov 15 10:07:27 server mysqld_safe: 171115 10:07:27 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/server.local.err'.
Nov 15 10:07:27 server mysqld_safe: 171115 10:07:27 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
Nov 15 10:07:27 server systemd: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 15 10:07:28 server systemd: Failed to start MySQL Percona Server.
Nov 15 10:07:28 server systemd: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Nov 15 10:07:28 server systemd: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of mysqld.service.
Nov 15 10:07:28 server systemd: mysqld.service failed.
Nov 15 10:07:28 server systemd: Started Service Status Monitor.
Nov 15 10:07:28 server systemd: Starting Service Status Monitor...
```

Even though it's stating in there that it failed to start the Percona server, it appears to be working as my website is still doing mysql queries. I know very little about mysql admin and was hoping a mysql guru could shed some light on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is here: `"A mysqld process already exists"`. It can't start mysqld because another mysqld process is already running, and using the same port. You need to kill that process before the one you tried to start can start.

---

Re your comment:

Since this is CentOS 7, I assume mysql.service is being called by systemd.

In my experience, if you start mysqld "ad hoc" without using systemd, then systemd has no idea that it's running, and tries to start mysqld on its own. Systemd also cannot shut down an instance of mysqld unless it started that instance.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. As I've restarted the server and checked the logs, mysqld.service continues to try and restart every 10 seconds. Any idea how to check what is triggering or calling it?

Answer (score -1):

the mysqld process is active,`ps -ef |grep mysqld` ,kill -9 {}